# I am not getting the Firebase Data in correct format

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I might be missing something really silly here. But I am not getting the firebase data in correct format.

**Person.java**

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String hobby;

    public Person(){

    }


    public Person(String name , String email , String hobby){
        this.name= name;
        this.email = email;
        this.hobby = hobby;

    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setHobby(String hobby) {
        this.hobby = hobby;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getHobby() {
        return hobby;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
//    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    List<Person> person;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        person = new ArrayList<>();
//        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        context = this;



        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pagerView);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), person, context));


    }


    class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        String[] tabsArray;
        private List<Person> personInAdapter = new ArrayList<>();
        private Context context;

//        int icons[] = {R.drawable.white_home, R.drawable.white_heart,
//                R.drawable.white_star, R.drawable.white_heart, R.drawable.white_star};

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Person> person, Context context) {
            super(fm);
            personInAdapter = person;
            this.context = context;
            tabsArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.TABS);
        }


//        @Override
//        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
//            return tabsArray[position];
//        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return MyFragment.getInstance(position );
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return personInAdapter.size();
        }
    }
}
```

MyFragment.java

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private TextView upperText;
    private TextView lowerText;
    List<Person> personInAdapter = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    public static MyFragment getInstance(int position) {
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", position);
        myFragment.setArguments(args);

        return myFragment;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
        upperText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.myFragmentUpperText);
        lowerText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.myFragmentLowerText);
        databaseReference = FirebaseUtil.getBaseRef().child("Person");
        int i = getArguments().getInt("position");
         ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
                Person person = dataSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);

                Log.e("Data In Person  ", person.toString());
                upperText.setText(person.getName());
                lowerText.setText(person.getEmail());
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // Getting Post failed, log a message
                // [START_EXCLUDE]

            }
        };
       databaseReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);
//        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
//        if (bundle != null) {
//            textView.setText("The value is" +i);
//        }

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }
}
```

[image: MyFragment ScreenShot]

From the LogCat :

```
 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -Ka45AN7nk3rAqTGfcp3 found on class testfirebase.com.testprojectforall.Person
 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -Ka45AN20cVBNFqbCwUj found on class testfirebase.com.testprojectforall.Person
 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -Ka45ANAi__pHJhzwjIa found on class testfirebase.com.testprojectforall.Person
 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -Ka45AN9pBd21aiHbS6i found on class testfirebase.com.testprojectforall.Person
 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -Ka45AN8Q1Y5GHOWRnpP found on class testfirebase.com.testprojectforall.Person
 E/Data In Person: testfirebase.com.testprojectforall.Person@b56a0f3
 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -Ka45AN7nk3rAqTGfcp3 found on class testfirebase.com.testprojectforall.Person
 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -Ka45AN20cVBNFqbCwUj found on class testfirebase.com.testprojectforall.Person
 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -Ka45ANAi__pHJhzwjIa found on class testfirebase.com.testprojectforall.Person
 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -Ka45AN9pBd21aiHbS6i found on class testfirebase.com.testprojectforall.Person
 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -Ka45AN8Q1Y5GHOWRnpP found on class testfirebase.com.testprojectforall.Person
 E/Data In Person: testfirebase.com.testprojectforall.Person@7dec1b0
 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -Ka45AN7nk3rAqTGfcp3 found on class testfirebase.com.testprojectforall.Person
 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -Ka45AN20cVBNFqbCwUj found on class testfirebase.com.testprojectforall.Person
 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -Ka45ANAi__pHJhzwjIa found on class testfirebase.com.testprojectforall.Person
 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -Ka45AN9pBd21aiHbS6i found on class testfirebase.com.testprojectforall.Person
 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -Ka45AN8Q1Y5GHOWRnpP found on class testfirebase.com.testprojectforall.Person
 E/Data In Person: testfirebase.com.testprojectforall.Person@6fc4829
 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -Ka45AN7nk3rAqTGfcp3 found on class testfirebase.com.testprojectforall.Person
 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -Ka45AN20cVBNFqbCwUj found on class testfirebase.com.testprojectforall.Person
 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -Ka45ANAi__pHJhzwjIa found on class testfirebase.com.testprojectforall.Person
 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -Ka45AN9pBd21aiHbS6i found on class testfirebase.com.testprojectforall.Person
 W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -Ka45AN8Q1Y5GHOWRnpP found on class testfirebase.com.testprojectforall.Person
 E/Data In Person: testfirebase.com.testprojectforall.Person@3e83de5
```

Sample from my firebase Console :

[image: Database Snapshot from Firebase Console]

I am getting the text but not able to set. What wrong am I doing in handling the firebase requests?

Comment: I just went through the same learning curve a few weeks ago. This is one thing I don't think they make clear enough in their documentation (IMHO). And trying to debug it doesn't help at all.

Comment: Yeah Exactly I have been trying this for last 5 hours :D :D but no was not able to get any relevant information on the logcat and even on the internet. But Frank was really quick and to the point. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attaching a `ValueEventListener` to the `Person` node in your database:

```
    ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
            Person person = dataSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);

            Log.e("Data In Person  ", person.toString());
            upperText.setText(person.getName());
            lowerText.setText(person.getEmail());
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Getting Post failed, log a message
            // [START_EXCLUDE]

        }
    };
   databaseReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```

This means that your `onDataChange` will be called with all the data under the `Person` node. So in your case that will be multiple people.

In you `onDataChange` you need to handle this by looping over the child nodes in the snapshot:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot personSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Person person = personSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);
        Log.i("Data In Person  ", person.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndroidBeginner You just received an excellent answer! I still would like to point out that this is exactly what the logs were telling you. The `getValue()` method is trying to set the key generated by a `push()` method to some field inside the `Person.class`. As there is no field for this, it fails and instead prints the key with the message that this wont work. You were just a level too high.

Comment: Thanks a lot Frank :)